# Calculating N-type enhanced MOSFET gain with two different equations brings me a different result?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, gain

[image]

Hi, take a look at this problem from my notebook. Leave alone the fact that the resistor should actually be 1,111.111, it is not related.

If they claim that VGS=2 and Vs is connected to ground it means that VG = Vin =5V. And if VD = Vout = 10V.

If it's true, than the gain should be Vout/Vin = 10/5 = 2. But if I calculate it with the different formula gmRd then the gain is indeed 6.6.

How is that possible?

Comment: the resistor should not, in fact, be 1111.111 Ω, because that level of precision would cost a ridiculous amount of money for no benefit. Use a 1.1 kΩ ±5% resistor and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I see. The first is I think you've mistaken the actual gate-source voltage \$V_{GS}=5V\$ for the MOSFET threshold voltage, which is called \$V_{GS,th}=2V\$ in your text.

Second, they are not calculating gain as a function of pure DC input and output voltages - e.g. Vout/Vin because they are talking about *small signal* gain. In *small signal* gain, you make a "small" change in input voltage (e.g. 0.1V), and measure the change in the output voltage (e.g. 0.66V). The base DC levels for your input voltage and output voltage aren't a factor.

Comment: Thanks!
So does the formula 2k(Vgs-Vgsth) and then Gm*Rd give a better representation of small signals?

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd \$g_m\$ is the notation for "small-scale transconductance". It is an implicit assumption of this formula.

Comment: I understand, so is the final gain result (6.6) is roughly giving back the average gain that a small signal would get?

Comment: Right - a very small signal would not significantly change the DC bias level of the system. The small-signal gain runs out of steam when you start wanting to get significant fractions of a volt change on the input or output. At that point, you need to start changing your analysis technique (e.g. SPICE).